# How can I change the cursor image in python soya?

Tags: python, opengl, sdl

[Soya](http://home.gna.org/oomadness/en/soya3d/index.html) is a 3D game framework for python.

How can I change the cursor image to/from a different image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but,

**dir() function is your friend. Use it see what methods and attributes are available for "Cursor" class.**

From the look of it, it doesn't have one. How ever the parent class allows you to set a shape.

- http://home.gna.org/soya/soya.cursor.html

This class is derived from soya.Volume

- http://home.gna.org/soya/soya.html#Volume

It seems to have a function called set_shape.